# ¿Cómo se trabaja con el setInterval en un switch en reducers?

Tags: react-redux, setinterval, reducer

Necesito hacer un contador automático en React-Redux y  me arroja este error... `state + 1`

```
const initialState = 0;
export default function jueReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case START:
     let inicio =  setInterval(() => {
        state + 1;
      }, 1000);
      return inicio
    case RESET:
      return initialState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```